# Is there any way to communicate with the I2C with Java, without Pi4J?

Tags: i2c, java

With Pi4J, I can communicate with I2C with Java. But is there any way I can communicate with I2C with Java, without Pi4J. Just by using Linux internal...shell-ish...command?

I want to read and write data.

Comment: Not Pi specific.  The I2C device is implemented as a file.  If Java allows you to read and write files you can use I2C.

Comment: @joan How can I do that? Can I use ProcessBuilder to work with the file? Any commands etc?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the Pi.  This is the wrong site for the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementation example available here: https://github.com/mattjlewis/diozero/tree/master/diozero-core/src/main/java/com/diozero/internal/provider/builtin/i2c
Two versions, one via JNI, the other using a Java RandomAccessFile. Note that for the second Java implementation a small bit of C code is required to run an ioctl command to setup the file for I2C (I2C select slave).